# <fmt:formatNumber in jstl need to $ symbol

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

In our struts app, we have been using `<fmt:formatNumber>` is so many places to show currency. By default the tag takes browser setting and showing the currency symbol. If locale is "en_US" showing ($), if "en_UK" showing (euro).

But I want to show dollar alone to my whole application. Is there any way to change in single place to reflects.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I really hope it was showing GBP (£) for en_UK and not Euro (€)?

Answer (score 4):

> *But I want to show dollar alone to my whole application.*

Just specify the `currencySymbol` attribute.

```html
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" value="${product.price}" />
```

#### See also:

- [`<fmt:formatNumber>` tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html)

Comment: Apparently, the OP used `<fmt:formatNumber>` all over the place, so the OP wants an easier way to just add 1 simple locale somewhere that all `<fmt:formatNumber>` can "view" all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

In `<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>`, you can use scope attribute and put value to application. By that way, it will save Locale value to en_US for the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using properties file. I would suggest having a properties file based on the language locale instead of country locale.

E.g. If you have `ApplicationResource.en_US.properties` and `ApplicationResources.en_UK.properties`, rather have `ApplicationResources.en.properties` and have a key/value entry that displays only dollar.

Alternatively, you would set your locale to only `en_US` **before** displaying your currency. Example:

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${val}"
                  type="currency"/>
```

Comment: ya i have seen <fmt:setLocale>, but in my app, I have been using <fmt:formatNumber> in so many places, I don't want to repeat the locale setting in all jsp's tat would be difficult for my future maintenance., so is there any way to set this locale in on place.

Comment: You could set locale on `response.setLocale()` method instead, but that would not be wise if your are doing internalization.